# SCSS ampersand showing as red highlight in Sublime text?

Tags: css, sass, sublimetext3

I'm using sublime text and for some reason get this red highlight over SCSS code when using ampersand:

[image]

I have both SCSS and SASS packages installed and tried changing the view preference from SCSS to SASS ->SCSS(this just makes all the code white)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm using a [different](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) syntax highlighting color scheme (disclaimer: I'm the author) along with the latest dev build of ST4, and when using the Sass syntax, I get errors on all the brackets `{}`, but not on `container`. Switching to SCSS gives normal highlighting. What build of Sublime Text are you using? You can find it under `Help → About Sublime Text`. Also, can you provide links to the SASS and SCSS packages you're using?

Comment: @MattDMo hey matt, I was able to solve it. Apparently, I have 3 modes for SCSS that I can set, after trying all 3 I was able to find one that worked on my file. Only problem is now I need to manually select it for all SCSS files, will have to find a default to set for this. All 3 SCSS packages were just named SCSS lol

Comment: You can select `View → Syntax → Open all with current extension as…` and choose the syntax you want to use for files with the current extension.